# Retrieve previous month from date column that contains MONYYYY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I need to change a date value that is coming from a table in the form of May2013 (MonYYYY). The column itself is a VARCHAR

In my select statement, I am looking to retrieve the previous month (Apr2013). I've done some research and found the following, if I were using SYSDATE:

```
select to_date(add_months(sysdate, 'MONYYY')-1) from dual
```

How do I make it work for the date structure I have above? I've tried:

```
select to_date(add_months(date.datetable, MONYYY)-1) from datetable
```

Comment: Firstly, never store a date in a varchar, secondly, ADD_MONTHS() is a function with two parameters so you need a comma before the -1, thirdly, you have the parameters for TO_DATE() and ADD_MONTHS() the wrong way round, fourthly you need to quote `'MONYYY'`, fifthly it's `'MONYYYY'` (extra Y), lastly it's `datetable.date` not `date.datetable`.

Answer (score 2):

`ADD_MONTHS` function needs a date variable as input. So, first you need to convert your varchar column to date type and then apply the `add_months` function.

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE ('May2013', 'monyyyy'), -1) FROM DUAL;
```

The return type will be date. In this case, it returns 0th hour of first day of April.